# Excel VSTO 2016 - Show function arguments dialog for UDF

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, office-interop, xll

I have a XLL library with UDFs used in Excel. Users can use the UDFs by either directly typing the UDF name in a cell, or by launching the **Function Wizard Dialog** and search for the specific UDFs, which in turn will launch the **Function Argument Dialog** for that specific UDF.

I'm now trying to create a **Ribbon** with *MSVS2017/C#/Office-Interop/VSTO* which show **Gallery Controls** with drop down menus containing all UDFs as items.  When a user clicks on any of the UDF items in the drop down, the **Function Arguments Dialog** should be displayed for that UDF.

How do you show the **Function Arguments Dialog** for a specific UDF using Office-Interop/C#/VSTO, or even for any built in function?

I have found very little on the topic after doing some googling. This [question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/867b4ff3-adea-45d2-83e4-3f474eaabb5f/how-to-launch-excel-function-arguments-windows-in-c?forum=exceldev) is spot on, but the solution code doesn't work.

I found this documentation on the [Office Interop namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.aspx), and more precisely this on different [built-in dialogs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlbuiltindialog.aspx). But I can't find anything about the **Function Arguments Dialog** there.

It seems to be quite easy to launch the **Function Wizard Dialog**. It can be done with this:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Dialogs[Excel.XlBuiltInDialog.xlDialogFunctionWizard].Show();
```

I hope you can open the **Function Arguments Dialog** for any UDF with a similar call.
Do I have to give up trying Office-Interop and use a [Excel C Api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687829.aspx) call? Or should I try some 3rd party tool like [Excel-DNA](https://excel-dna.net/) or [Add-in Express](https://www.add-in-express.com)?

Comment: @CindyMeister I have improved the question, please remove the on hold.

Comment: I can't re-open it myself, any more than I could close it by myself. But I have put in a vote which will put it in the queue...

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution! You have to populate the **active cell** with a valid **UDF formula** before you call the **Function Dialog Wizard**, then it shows the **Function Arguments Dialog**!

This [VBA code](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/277436-open-function-dialog-vba.html) gave me a hint.

So the following C# code works:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveCell.Formula = "=zAirAtmTPFC()";
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Dialogs[Excel.XlBuiltInDialog.xlDialogFunctionWizard].Show();
```

The zAirAtmTPFC() is an UDF function in an XLL.